# End of statement expected. VB.NET Razor

Tags: vb.net, razor

Could someone tell me what's wrong with this code? The compiler is complaining about something with my ActionLinks.

```
  @grid.GetHtml(
columns:=New WebGridColumn() {grid.Column("cubeName"),
                              grid.Column("bracketFilter"),
                              grid.Column("description"),
                              grid.Column("", header:="Action", canSort:=False, format:=@@<text>
                                                                                            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", New With {.id = item.cubeid, .appid = item.appid}) |
                                                                                            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", New With {.id = item.cubeid, .appid = item.appid}) |
                                                                                            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", New With {.id = item.cubeid, .appid = item.appid})
                                                                                        </text>)},
htmlAttributes:=New With {.class = "tblnAdmin"})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For multiple-line statements you have to wrap your code in parentheses.  Try:

```
  @(grid.GetHtml(
columns:=New WebGridColumn() {grid.Column("cubeName"),
                              grid.Column("bracketFilter"),
                              grid.Column("description"),
                              grid.Column("", header:="Action", canSort:=False, format:=@@<text>
                                                                                            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", New With {.id = item.cubeid, .appid = item.appid}) |
                                                                                            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", New With {.id = item.cubeid, .appid = item.appid}) |
                                                                                            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", New With {.id = item.cubeid, .appid = item.appid})
                                                                                        </text>)},
htmlAttributes:=New With {.class = "tblnAdmin"}))
```